# How to stop execution of 'when' condition for second time

Tags: xml, xslt

My problem is: I am looping the  tag in the below xml and doing a lookup and performing some logic on that(in xsl after when condition), But I do not want to perform the logic to the second coverage with the same category- category1.

The first time in the loop I will get coverage code as -GOLD and lookup will return values as -category 1 and will perform logic.
2nd time in the loop I will get coverage code as -SILVER and lookup will return value as -category1 (same category) so I don't want to perform the logic after xsl **when** condition even the condition satisfied.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this ( I want to achieve- For single existence of different lookup value only (here category1) perform the logic single time. Blow xsl when the condition will execute 2 times for **category1**, but I want to execute logic for -**category1** for one time even I iterate loop for all coverages.

Below are my XML, lookup XML, and xsl ( I added pseudo code please ignore any issues, my main focus is to find the solution for the problem that I asked above).

**XML:**

```
<policy>
<location>
<coverage>
<coverageCode>GOLD</<coverageCode>
</coverage>
<coverage>
<coverageCode>SILVER</<coverageCode>
</coverage>
<coverage>
<coverageCode>MONEY</<coverageCode>
</coverage>
</location>
</policy>
```

**Lookup xml: propertylookup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>

    
    <Property name="GOLD">category1</Property>
    <Property name="SILVER">category1</Property>
    <Property name="MONEY">category2</Property>
<property>
```

**Below is xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    extension-element-prefixes="iipxsl" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:variable name="coverageprops"
        select="document('propertylookup.xml')" />
<xsl:template match="/policy">
<policyresults>
<xsl:call-template name="policy">
<xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
</policyresults>

<xsl:template name="policy">
<xsl:for-each select="$node/location/coverage">
<xsl:variable name="covcodevalue" select="coverageCode"
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$coverageprops/Properties/Property[@name=$covcodevalue] and $coverageprops/Properties/Property[@name=$covcodevalue] ='category1'" >

---Some logic here---

</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="coverageprops"  as="document-node()" select="doc('propertylookup.xml')"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- First bind the categories to the coverage in a different mode -->
    <xsl:variable name="policyWithCategories" as="element(policy)">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="policy" mode="bindCategory"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <policyresults>
      <!-- Apply the new xml in the standerd mode  -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$policyWithCategories"/>
    </policyresults>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- bind the categorie (via een attribute but it can be anything you like) in mode  mode="bindCategory" -->
  <xsl:template match="coverage" mode="bindCategory">
    <xsl:variable name="covcodevalue" select="coverageCode/text()"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="category" select="$coverageprops/Properties/Property[@name=$covcodevalue]/text()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- since there are only elements and text-nodes in your example we only need this template to copy teh rest of the xml. in this bindCategory-mode -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="bindCategory">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- instead off for-each it is best-practise just to use the xslt-engine using apply-templates -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- And finally do something with the coverage if it does not have a same preceding-siblinf with the attribute @category-->
  <xsl:template match="coverage">
    <xsl:variable name="category" select="@category"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[@category=$category])">
      <!-- Some logic here: i.e. -->
      <firstCategory>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*,*"/>
      </firstCategory>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Siebe Jongebloed , Your answer gave me the idea.